# Get protobuf extension file for xampp

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

i need to use this from  google
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/samples/upload-offline-conversion?hl=de

And for this i need 2 things, according to the composer.json here
https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/blob/HEAD/composer.json

I need ""grpc/grpc": "^1.36.0"," and "google/protobuf": "^3.21.5",

grpc i got from here, https://pecl.php.net/package/gRPC/1.43.0/windows, download and put it in "php\ext" and activated it in the php ini.

But i cant figure out how to get such .dll file ? for protobuf.
I mean pecl has a site for it https://pecl.php.net/package-search.php?pkg_name=protobuf

But if download it, i only have a bunch of *.h files.

i tried to understand it for 4-5 hours now, and i just dont get it.

All i need is a protobuf extension file for my local xampp installation so that i can run "composer install" without errors.

Comment: Per https://github.com/protobuf-php/protobuf-plugin there doesn't seem to be a windows version ready made. You might have to compile it from source yourself

Comment: Or perhaps you can work around it by running your php stack in Linux (via WSL or docker, for example)

Comment: Hi, is there no site where you can download the compiled file? I just need for a local installation for XAMPP

Comment: A tiny bit more googling reveals https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases which appears to have Windows-specific files. There seem to be some instructions here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf?tab=readme-ov-file#overview . I hope that's the right thing

Comment: This is Not helping me ^^ But from my understanding so far, you can skip it with "composer install --ignore-platform-req=ext-protobuf". But Now i get "Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentParser' not found "